# how to read the content of text files having white space between file name?

Tags: php, text, file-get-contents, readfile

I want to get the content in a text file and I am using `file_get_contents()`

But problem starts when I try to read files having white space into the file name.

for example: `/home/project/text cv.txt` cannot be read using `file_get_contents()`.

Is there any alternative to read .txt files ?

Comment: try replacing spaces with "\ "

Comment: I tried that too....but not getting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use realpath() to wrap the URI to your file:

```
$path = realpath( dirname(__FILE__).'/../_files/file with space.txt' );
$data = file_get_contents($path);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a hint in the documentation:
`If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().`

Comment: I am using linux system and I passed url 

$filenames="/home/project/news4u/web/".urlencode('ede ede10696.txt');
$content = file_get_contents($filenames);
echo $content;

It is resulting empty.

Answer (score -1):

try `file_get_contents(text&nbsp;cv);` or `file_get_contents(text%20cv);`